# How can I turn into a cat?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

When I have the feather item activated and a bell in my item storage, I can't turn into a cat. When I press <kbd>-</kbd> to put the bell from storage in front of me and collect it again, it just goes back into the storage area. I can repeat this as many times as I want, but I can't turn into a cat.

I like being a cat. How can I reject the feather and embrace the bell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every power-up has a priority level. Picking up something of equal or higher priority will activate it, but picking up something of lower priority will put it into storage instead. You'll have to forcibly remove your current power-up somehow (e.g. get hit) in order to apply one of a lower priority.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Toomai's answer, there is another layer to the onion of the power-ups in this game - The Golden Leaf (white Tanooki suit).  If you have the white Tanooki Suit on any character, **no other power-ups** will 'stick'.  This is as-designed since that power-up basically makes you invincible and only shows up when you are having trouble with a level.